# Problem with importing Lemmatization from gensim

Tags: python, numpy, gensim, lemmatization

I am trying to use Gensim packages as written below:

```
import re, numpy as np, pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint

# Gensim
import gensim, spacy, logging, warnings
import gensim.corpora as corpora
from gensim.utils import lemmatize, simple_preprocess
from gensim.models import CoherenceModel
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

But i keep getting the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'lemmatize' from 'gensim.utils' (/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/envs/virt_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gensim/utils.py)
```

I am using gensim v4.0.1, Python 3.8, numpy 1.20.0.

Has anyone encountered this kinda problem lately? Thank you

Comment: There is no function `lemmatize` in [`gensim.utils`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/utils.html) in version 4.0 of gensim.  [It existed](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim_3.8.3/utils.html#gensim.utils.lemmatize) in 3.8.3, but I don't know much about gensim, so I don't know if it was completely removed or moved to a different part of the code.

Comment: From the current library```        if lemmatize is not None:
            raise NotImplementedError(
                'The lemmatize parameter is no longer supported. '
                'If you need to lemmatize, use e.g. <https://github.com/clips/pattern>. '
                'Perform lemmatization as part of your tokenization function and '
                'pass it```

Answer (score 3):

Gensim only ever previously wrapped the lemmatization routines of another library (`Pattern`) – which was not a particularly modern/maintained option, so was removed from Gensim-4.0.

Users should choose & apply their own lemmatization operations, if any, as a preprocessing step before applying Gensim's algorithms. Some Python libraries offering lemmatization include:

- Pattern (Gensim's previously-included option): https://github.com/clips/pattern
- NLTK: https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html#nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer
- UDPipe: https://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/udpipe
- Spacy: https://spacy.io/api/lemmatizer
- Stanza: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/

Comment: ...this is quite helpful.Thank you